# jQuery datepicker- range with 3 fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm creating a web form, and I have the following 3 input fields that I am using Date Picker for: Arrive By, Start Date, and End Date. (It's for a trade show exhibit)

The shipment needs to be there by the "Arrive By" date, and the trade show lasts from "Start Date" until "End Date".

I was able to create the range for the "Start Date" & "End Date" fields, but now the client wants to ensure that the start/end range cannot be before the "Arrive By" date, and nothing can be before the current date.

I assume if I limit the "Arrive By" date to not be able to pick earlier than the current date, and then impose the entered "Arrive By" date as the beginning of the range for "Start Date" I will achieve what they want. (Do I need to disable the start/end fields until an arrive by date is entered?)

Unfortunately, this would seem to require lots of advanced code which is a little out of my skill set. Hopefully someone can get me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  You could do validation on submit to make sure the user selected appropriate dates that meet the requirements or you could use the Datepicker [restrict date range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) options to limit the available dates based on the selected value of the other Datepicker.  Take a look at the Datepicker [select a date range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) feature to see how you can set the min/max selectable date.

Here's an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59hqr/) that demonstrates this.  This wasn't thoroughly tested, so you might have to play with the behavior to get it exactly how you want (for instance, you probably want to change the `to` min date as well when you change the `arrive` date).

HTML:

```
<label for="arrive">Arrive</label>
<input type="text" id="arrive" name="arrive">
<br />
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Javascript:

```
$("#arrive").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $("#arrive").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am already using the date range feature, but I need to involve a 3rd field, as well as the current date. I am unsure how to make that happen.

Comment: That gets me about halfway there.
I need to make sure a date before current date cannot be selected.

Comment: The rest is for you to figure out yourself.  This site is to help you solve technical issues, not to do the work for you.  Here's a hint, when you initialize the datepickers, set the `mindate` to today.

Comment: Thank you Coda17, I should be able to figure it out... I can't seem to add mindate to the to field using the above code. (I get the feeling they will still want it on that field.) Any hints?

Comment: Yes, read the documentation on the JQuery datepicker pages that I linked.  There are multiple examples of setting a minimum date.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Arrive By date captured in a seperate field (another datepicker?) to the field that you're configuring with the start and end date range?

If ArriveBy is in a datepicker, you can throw an event when a date is selected, and then use that to change a property on the other date picker to make it the new minimum(/maximum?) From memory it's something like

```
$("#ArriveBy").datepicker({
      onClose: function(selected) {
        $("#StartEndRange").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
      }
});
```

Not 100% if that exactly answers your scenario, but hopefully is of some help.

Comment: Yes, there are 3 date fields, all using datepicker. 
There is already a range for the Start & End fields, arriveBy is just it's own field, but now needs to somehow interact with the other 2.

Comment: Ok, so you can use the method above to adjust the min and max ranges on each, once a value is selected in any of the three. So adjust the arrive by date, the above can be used to change the range on the other two, and so on. Does that help?